# Eliminar un atributo JSON con metallave en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, json, mvc

Tengo la siguiente estructura JSON en mi columna json de mi tabla activos:

```
{
   "activo":[
        {"id":0,"name":"activo","titulo":"Longitud","contenido":"35 CM"}
        {"id":1,"name":"activo","titulo":"Volumen","contenido":"55 CM"}
    ]
}
```

Accedo a los atributos editándolos de ésta manera:

```
 $activos = Activo::find($id); //Identifica al activo de la tabla
 $json=json_decode($activos->json); //recupera la columna json en una variable decodificandolo
 $json->activo[1]->titulo='nuevo titulo'; //Cambia el titulo del índice uno
 $json->activo[1]->titulo->contenido='nuevo contenido';
 $activos->json=json_encode($json); //Retorna la representación JSON
 $activos->save(); //Procede a guardarlos a la base de datos 
 $activos->refresh();
```

Quisiera poder bajo ésta metodologia poder eliminar el índice uno de activos (activos[1]).
Espero puedan ayudarme con alguna solución

Comment: Funciona lo que tienes? Después del `json_decode`, vas a tener un array, pero accedes a `titulo` como si fuera el atributo de un objeto. Para eliminar un elemento de un array puedes usar [array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-splice.php)

Comment: Logré eliminar el atributo con la herramienta 'unset' de php, simplemente realicé la metodología que anteriormente anexé.  unset($json->activo[1]);

Comment: Genial, puedes escribir una respuesta explicando cómo lo resolviste y aceptarla, así le sirve a otros con el mismo problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolví el problema con la herramienta de unset que ofrece php, siguiendo la misma metodología, realicé lo siguiente:

```
 $activos = Activo::find($id); //Identifica la fila de acuerdo a la ID
 $json=json_decode($activos->json); //Decodifica el campo JSON para editarse
 unset($json->activo[1]); //Ofrece la herramienta unset eliminar campos o variables, elimina todo el contenido el subnivel 1
 $activos->json=json_encode($json); //retorna la representación JSON
 $activos->save(); //Procede a guardar la modificación a la base de datos
 $activos->refresh();
```

Por el momento lo estoy trabajando así, estoy a su disposición de leer otras propuestas  para la posible solución del problema.